# Passing ORDER BY using variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have the next code but I am not getting the desired result by using ORDER BY:

```php
// OrderBy WHERE Conditions
if ($sort_by == "0")    $sortby_condition = "ORDER BY mv_user_ranking.ranking_date DESC ";
if ($sort_by == "1")    $sortby_condition = "ORDER BY mv_user_info.age DESC ";
if ($sort_by == "2")    $sortby_condition = "ORDER BY mv_user_info.sex DESC ";

$query ="SELECT * FROM mv_user_info 
         LEFT JOIN mv_user_lang_interested ON mv_user_lang_interested.uid = mv_user_info.uid        
         LEFT JOIN mv_user_disponibility   ON mv_user_disponibility.uid   = mv_user_info.uid    
         LEFT JOIN mv_user_ranking         ON mv_user_ranking.uid         = mv_user_info.uid   

         WHERE country ='$country' AND city = '$city' AND
               mv_user_lang_interested.english = '1' AND
               mv_user_lang_interested.english_level = '2' AND 
               mv_user_info.uid != '$uid'"

         .$sortby_condition.

         "LIMIT 0, 50";

echo $query;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: it seems ok... Have you tried to see what the resulting (that you echo) query returns in phpmyadmin or similar tool?

Comment: *"I am not getting the desired result"* <-- then what do you get? And what do you desire?

Comment: It is like the order by sentence was ignored.

Comment: the variable `$sort_by` doesn't have the value you expect. Inspect its value.

Comment: echo `$sort_by` to see what the value is. You could change it to an `if/elseif/else`, to give a default sort in case the value is not `0,1,2`

Comment: I have found the error. The error was in the "echo" sentences I wrote to check the result. I am parsing the results using JSON. So the echo sentence did not let to parse it correct. Deleting the echo sentences it works perfectly.

Comment: If `$sort_by` is an integer, use `if ($sortby = 1)` etc. (or you're comparing strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks interesting, ok lets try it

```
// OrderBy WHERE Conditions
//i don't know what was passed as $sort_by value
//perhaps you may try 
$sort_by = (integer)$sort_by;  //casting 

if ($sort_by == 0){$sortby_condition = "ORDER BY mv_user_ranking.ranking_date DESC ";}//if () if() three times not an optimize way, try if, elseif
elseif ($sort_by == 1){    $sortby_condition = "ORDER BY mv_user_info.age DESC ";}//write your code in block "{}" this may prevent your block of statement mix
elseif ($sort_by == "2"){    $sortby_condition = "ORDER BY mv_user_info.sex DESC ";}

$query ="SELECT * FROM mv_user_info 
         LEFT JOIN mv_user_lang_interested ON mv_user_lang_interested.uid = mv_user_info.uid        
         LEFT JOIN mv_user_disponibility   ON mv_user_disponibility.uid   = mv_user_info.uid    
         LEFT JOIN mv_user_ranking         ON mv_user_ranking.uid         = mv_user_info.uid   

         WHERE country ='$country' AND city = '$city' AND
               mv_user_lang_interested.english = '1' AND
               mv_user_lang_interested.english_level = '2' AND 
               mv_user_info.uid != '$uid'"

    .$sortby_condition.

    "LIMIT 0, 50";

echo $query;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

if any problem feel free to ask
better you give whole lines of text you right, then We can answer you better :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically,  i don't see any issue with the query but you can do one thing: Create another query over this query, so that this query becomes a subquery and then sort from the above query. Your code will look like this:

```
// OrderBy WHERE Conditions
if ($sort_by == "0")    $sortby_condition = "ORDER BY ranking_date DESC ";
if ($sort_by == "1")    $sortby_condition = "ORDER BY age DESC ";
if ($sort_by == "2")    $sortby_condition = "ORDER BY sex DESC ";

//Note I have removed the table name from order by clause because in the super-query we will only have column name.

$query ="
Select * From (
 SELECT * FROM mv_user_info 
     LEFT JOIN mv_user_lang_interested ON mv_user_lang_interested.uid = mv_user_info.uid        
     LEFT JOIN mv_user_disponibility   ON mv_user_disponibility.uid   = mv_user_info.uid    
     LEFT JOIN mv_user_ranking         ON mv_user_ranking.uid         = mv_user_info.uid   

     WHERE country ='$country' AND city = '$city' AND
           mv_user_lang_interested.english = '1' AND
           mv_user_lang_interested.english_level = '2' AND 
           mv_user_info.uid != '$uid'
     LIMIT 0, 50) as a ".$sortby_condition;

echo $query;

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I hope this helps